# How to group points with given tolerance in Matlab

Tags: matlab

There's set of points in 2D plane.

```
points = [2, 2; 
          10, 12; 
          1, 1; 
          3,3; 
          5, 10]
```

Some points are in close proximity to others and form clusters/clouds. How to replace such cluster with one point given that cluster can be on area specified by some treshold `t`?

```
output = [2, 2; 
          10, 12;  
          5, 10]
```

In more graphic way:

[image: example input and output]

Are there any algorithms/solutions that would be a good choice here?

Comment: Not sure what the logic is. Why would `2,2` be closer to `10,12` rather than, say, `1,1`?

Comment: @Paolo It's not. `[2,2]`, `[1,1]` and `[3,3]` have been merged into one point. `[10,12]` and `[5,10]` are too far away to have been merged.

Comment: `output = uniquetol(points, tol, 'ByRows', true, 'DataScale', 1);` should work.

Comment: @rahnema1 can you make this comment as an answer? It's good and easy solution for my problem and I want to accept it as final answer.

Comment: @Volz Sure, It is posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uniquetol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html):

```
output = uniquetol(points, tol, 'ByRows', true, 'DataScale', 1);
```

Note that [`uniquetol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html) uses absolute difference instead of squared difference.

Comment: @AlanKałuża I have edited my post. If you want you can undo your downvote.